# collection_select doesn't save through form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I know there is a lot of similar posts where people have the same problem, but none of them helped me. If i create new article then it won't have a category. But if i edit article created earlier in seed.rb then the category is updated. 
What's wrong?

Categories table:

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :articles
end
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
end
```

and then i have a _form file

```
<%= form_for(@article) do |f| %>

  <div class="title">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
        <%= f.label :content %>
        <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="category">
        <%= f.label :category %>
        <%= collection_select(:article, :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name) %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

There is a categories_controller file:

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @categories = Category.all
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @articles = @category.articles
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    if @category.update_attributes(category_params)
      redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @category.id)
    else
      render('index')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    Category.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Articles controller file:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
        @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render('new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    if @article.update_attributes(article_params)
        redirect_to(:action => 'show', :id => @article.id)
    else
        render('index')
    end
  end

  def delete
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    Article.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)
  end
end
```

Comment: use `f.collection_select`

Comment: `<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>` still do nothing

Comment: Please show articles_controller - categories_controller is irrelevant here.

Comment: I added articles_controller to the main post.

Comment: Ok i think i found the problem:P `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content)` should be `params.require(:article).permit(:title, :content, :category)` ?

Comment: @siwers - `:category_id`, not `:category`.  :)

Comment: Thank you!! How can I upvote your reputation?

Comment: @siwers They would have to post an actual answer below, and you could then upvote it (upvoting comments doesn't give any rewards unfortunately). If they don't do it though by whatever you think is a reasonable time (I'd say arguably by tomorrow if you care to wait), you could probably go ahead and post your own solution and accept it.

Comment: @PaulRichter ok I'll wait, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not building the association in the `articles#create` action. The category_id is being sent through your form, but you still need to to build the Active Record association. You could try something like this in the articles controller:

```
def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @article.category = @category
    if @article.save
        redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
        render('new')
    end
  end
```

Keep in mind, there are multiple ways to create an association. Your Article class has the following [five methods](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference) to manipulate the association:

```
@article.category  
@article.category= 
@article.build_category 
@article.create_category
@article.create_category!
```